# downsample bitmap image pixels actionscript 3?

Tags: image, actionscript-3, image-processing

I need to decrease the pixels in image from 480 X 480 to 30 X 30. This requires downsampling of pixels, i don't see any method to remove individual pixels in a bitmap image.

I need this downsampling because i'm studying distortion in image processing - on the brief side.

Any help in this would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there a problem with just making a new BitmapData that's 30x30 then setting up your algorithm to copy or set the appropriate pixels on the new BitmapData as opposed to trying to subtract away pixels from the initial one?

Comment: thanks, i'll try doing that. I had focused on only one solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.geom.Matrix;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

    public class DownSampling extends Sprite
    {
        private var _loader : Loader;
        public function DownSampling()
        {
            _loader = new Loader;
            _loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onImgLoaded);

            // Get the bitmap
            _loader.load(new URLRequest("https://appharbor.com/assets/images/stackoverflow-logo.png"));
        }

        private function onImgLoaded(e : Event) : void
        {
            var currentBitmapdata : BitmapData = Bitmap(_loader.content).bitmapData;
            var i : uint = 9;
            var downFactor : Number = 0.2;

            // this will reduce size by 20%
            var downMat : Matrix = new Matrix;
            downMat.scale(1 - downFactor, 1 - downFactor);

            while(--i)
            {
                // Create new bitmapdata but smaller
                var smallerImg : BitmapData = new BitmapData(currentBitmapdata.width * (1-downFactor), currentBitmapdata.height * (1-downFactor), true, 0);

                // Copy and apply scale
                smallerImg.draw(currentBitmapdata, downMat);

                // Add to stage and set alpha to 50%
                addChild(new Bitmap(smallerImg)).alpha = .5;

                // Apply the same transform next loop
                currentBitmapdata = smallerImg;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Result :
[image: Script result : downSampling]